# Where does VC++ 2008 linker find libraries?

Tags: linker, visual-c++-2008

I have VC++ 2008 C++ .DLL project that uses Opends60.lib (it is listed in Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies as "Opends60.lib")

I ported this project to VC++ 2010 (in different folder) and now link step fails with message:

Error   3   error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'opends60.lib'

So I figured I need to copy library from somewhere in 2008 project folder to 2010 project folder. Problem is - that library is nowhere to be found in 2008 project folder or anywhere on my hard drive!!! It is a mystery how 2008 project gets linked but somehow it does. Removing this library from 2008 project causes a bunch of unsolved externals, so it is found somewhere by linker.

Question: is there a way to find out where exactly linker from VC++ 2008 is finding this library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell - I used Windows Explorer (on Vista) to search for this file and it turns out by default it doesn't search in System and Program Files. More details is here:

https://superuser.com/questions/327699/windows-explorer-doesnt-search-system-or-program-files